# Symfony 4 : setup webroot in dev so browser can access files generated with webpack encore

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, webpack, symfony4

- I'm using Windows 10 and Wampp
- My Apache root points to `c:wamp/www`
- My Symfony projects is located at `c:wamp/www/my_project`

In **DEV**, I'm accessing my website using this URL:
`http://localhost/my_project/public/index.php`

I'm using **WebpackEncore**, and when I load my page, the browser tries to load assets (css and js generated in build directory) with paths where the `my_project/public` part is missing e.g.

`http://localhost/build/app.js`
but browsers expects something like:

`http://localhost/my_project/public/build/app.js`

I'm not familiar with redirections and `.htaccess`. I have been told I should set my webroot to solve this, so I guess that if I made my Apache root be `my_project/public` then it would work but I'm working on different projects and I don't want to change this parameter each time I switch form one project to another. Maybe this can be solved using an .htaccess ? Or setting up something else in Symfony config ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Apache `VirtualHost` feature.
You can configure one virtual host for each of your projects.
This way all your projects will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. I was hoping there would be a more simple solution though, like configuring symfony/asset so it creates the right url when in dev, or telling Encore to add the prefix in Url when in dev